# Responsive DIV element

Tags: html, static, responsive-design, width, percentage

I have this [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML):

```
<div class="styles container">
  <h1>Styles</h1>
</div>
<div class="preview container">
    <h1>Preview</h1>
</div>
```

I want the first div to be static. Let's say its width is to be 265 pixels. The `.preview` div should be next to it, but it should be responsive (by shrinking the window this div should also shrink). I tried with setting a % to this div, but still it goes below. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, DIV it's block element, and starts rendering from new line. There are few techniques to change the behavior. If you don't need to support IE6/IE7 you can use *inline-block* CSS style, e.g:

```
<div>
<div style="width:20%; display: inline-block;">
    <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div style="width:70%; display: inline-block;">
    <h1>2</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="styles">
  <h1>Styles</h1>
</div>
<div class="preview">
    <h1>Preview</h1>
</div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent{
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.styles{
    width:265px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.preview{
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Hope it will solve you problem.Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wau5f7ge/).